# .net core command does not generate solution file for omnisharp

Tags: vim, yeoman, .net-core, youcompleteme, omnisharp

I'm using YouCompleteMe with Omnisharp. I like the idea of being able to develop c# with auto completion in vim. I have installed .net core on my mac and generated a project. The project does not have a solution file. When I start Vim I see an error that the auto detection of the solution file has failed.

What am I missing here? Do I configure omnisharp to work around no solution file or should I be generating a .sln file?

Answer (score 2):

The reason YouCompleteMe expects a .sln file is because by default OmniSharp which is used by YouCompleteMe for C# expects a Mono project and not a DotNet core project. DotNet core does not require a solution file so OmniSharp must be compiled with Roslyn support instead. This will allow OmniSharp to understand a dot net core project.